# Compare two strings like date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

Need to compare two variables of type NSDate.
   One is the current date and the other is user selected date.

The user selects the date :

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;   // declared in h file

-(void)dateChange:(id)sender{
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyy"];
dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

userDebtInfo.duration = dateLabel.text;}
```

Validation Method :

```
-(IBAction) validation:(id)sender{
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

[dateFormat release];

 if ((userDebtInfo.debt_code == userTmp.debt_code) && ([userDebtInfo.duration compare:dateString]== NSOrderedDescending)))
            [bl updateUserMoneyValidation:userDebtInfo];  
 else
      [bl saveUserMoneyValidation:userDebtInfo];}
```

I have tested and is comparing two strings. Can someone help me with some advice about this condition, please?
  I want to compare if the selected date is after the current date to do insert or update the database.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do people always write `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherString]`, `[NSString stringWithString:otherString]` and similar **superfluous, processortime-wasting** calls?

Comment: @H2CO3 good call, man. I just found out I have a couple of these myself xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have two objects of type NSDate, you could use one of the NSDate comparison methods. For instance `[NSDate compare:]` which returns a `NSComparisonResult` (this is the same enum as returned by `[NSString compare:]`).

Answer (score 2):

You could use NSDate **compare** function

```
if([firstDate compare:secondUpdate] == NSOrderedAscending){
       //This will return YES if secondUpdate is the recent date between the two dates
}
```

NSOrderedAscending is a constant of NSComparisonResult
Here are the other constants you could compare to:

```
enum {
 NSOrderedAscending = -1,
 NSOrderedSame,
 NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```